Dimension of graded rings
Let $A=\oplus_{i \in N \cup \{0\}} A_i$ be a positively graded ring of dimension $d$ with $A_0=k$ and $k$ is a field. If $B$ is a Noetherian graded subring of $A$. Can we say dimension of $B$ cannot exceed $d$?
